# what should I use as placeholder for a html img element?

Tags: media

To keep it simple I've left some out of my img field.
here's my code:

```
$markup = t("<img src='%s' />", $img_src);
```

I've tried [`format_string()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/format_string/7) but that also retuns:

```
<img src="<em class="placeholder">path/to/image</em>">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would probably be better to use the [`theme_image()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_image/7) function for that:

```
$image_html = theme('image', array(
  'path' => $img_src,
  'alt' => 'Some alt',
  // etc
));
```

If you're hell bent on using `t()` then you need to use it with the `!` prefix, so the value is passed through without any checks/sanitisation:

```
$markup = t("<img src='!src' />", array('!src' => $img_src));
```

The [docs for `format_string()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/format_string/7) explains the different kinds of placeholders you can use, and which prefix you should use for each.

Comment: hmm seams I was a bit blind at the moment thanks for pointing out about the format string docs! But theme_image is a even better solution!